# Youtube Fails on device, works on Simulator

Tags: ios, swift, youtube

I'm using following code to display youtube videos:

```
webViewVideo.hidden = false

webViewVideo.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
webViewVideo.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false

let youtubeIfarme = "<html><body><iframe src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/\(youtubeId)?playsinline=1\" width=\"\(CGRectGetWidth(loadedView.frame) - CGFloat(16))\" height=\"\(CGRectGetHeight(webViewVideo.frame))\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>"

webViewVideo.loadHTMLString(youtubeIfarme, baseURL: NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleURL)
```

Which code works perfectly fine on simulator, however on real device it fails to load. I defined following as app transport security:

[transport security](http://prntscr.com/ah4xod)

Strange thing is that I downloaded [iOS Helper library](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper) but the result is the same. Moreover delegate methods are never called. On their github page they have a lot of opened issues so I guess that won't be my best choice to use.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

EDIT

I managed to debug how my html page looks inside UIWebView on simulator(by connecting it through Safari Develop):

```
<html><head></head><body><iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/KIiUqfxFttM?playsinline=1" width="359.0" height="350.0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></body></html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll have to answer my own question. The problem was that I used to show the video inside `UITableViewHeader` by implementing the needed delegates:

[viewForHeaderInSection](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:)

[heightForHeaderInSection](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:)

I have only one section so I returned value there only if `section == 0` I do not know what exactly causes this issue, but probably multiple calling of the method leads to this. What I did was to simply move the initialisation of `UIWebView` inside `viewWillAppear` and set it as `tableViewHeaderView`. So I'm now setting it only once and the problem is gone:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    dispatch_once(&token) {
        self.initHeader()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is OS Version of your simulator and the device? Is it same OS Version? May different UIWebView can trigger the error.

Check this also

[Playing youtube using <iframe> fails on iPhone, but still works for iPad under iOS 6 (both work fine on iOS 5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12667250/playing-youtube-using-iframe-fails-on-iphone-but-still-works-for-ipad-under-i)

Comment: Not helpful unfortunately. Device is Iphone 6 with iOS 9.2.1, Simulator is with 9.2